# Is there a way to negate a WHERE clause in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is my base query

```
select distinct a.projects , case when(billing_fy!=0)
then(select round(((sum(cost_project)/(sum(billing_fy)/((10/12)*365)))),2) 
     from table1 b      
     where a.projects = b.projects 
     group by projects)
else 0 end as "WIP days outstanding"
from table1 a
```

and it produces the following output

```
Projects                        WIP days outstanding
History - AURANGABAD - NASIK    0
History - PUNE - MUMBAI         0
History - NASIK - MUMBAI        89.92
History - SASAGRAM - MUMBAI     0
History - SASAGRAM - MUMBAI     1386.52
History - AURANGABAD - MUMBAI   83.25
```

Now what I need is to display all rows except the 4th row. The reason why I'm using a case statement in the first place is because if I did (the billing_fy!=0 clause is to prevent an error caused by dividing by 0)

```
select projects,
round(((sum(cost_project)/(sum(billing_fy)/((10/12)*365)))),2) as "WIP days outstanding"
from table1
where billing_fy!=0
group by projects;
```

I would get

```
Projects                        WIP days outstanding
History - SASAGRAM - MUMBAI     1386.52
History - NASIK - MUMBAI        89.92
History - AURANGABAD - MUMBAI   83.25
```

but I need to show for the other 2 places as well

```
History - AURANGABAD - NASIK    0
History - PUNE - MUMBAI         0
```

This query only displays the row I don't want.

```
select distinct a.projects , case when(billing_fy!=0)
then(select round(((sum(cost_project)/(sum(billing_fy)/((10/12)*365)))),2) from table1 b     where a.projects = b.projects group by projects)
else 0 end as "WIP days outstanding"
from table1 a
where (projects='History - SASAGRAM - MUMBAI' AND billing_fy=0);
```

and gives the output as expected

```
Projects                        WIP days outstanding
History - SASAGRAM - MUMBAI     0
```

**Now comes my question**. Is there a way in SQL to negate the WHERE clause? Like in C++ I would just have to use a not operator in front of the clause to negate it. Because basically, I want to display all rows EXCEPT the row above.

Right now, I've solved my problem of displaying all rows except the row I don't want by using the following code

```
select distinct a.projects , case when(billing_fy!=0)
then(select round(((sum(cost_project)/(sum(billing_fy)/((10/12)*365)))),2) from table1 b   where a.projects = b.projects group by projects)
else 0 end as "WIP days outstanding"
from table1 a
where projects not in ('History - SASAGRAM - MUMBAI') and billing_fy!=0
union all
select distinct a.projects , case when(billing_fy!=0)
then(select round(((sum(cost_project)/(sum(billing_fy)/((10/12)*365)))),2) from table1 b   where a.projects = b.projects group by projects)
else 0 end as "WIP days outstanding"
from table1 a
where projects not in ('History - SASAGRAM - MUMBAI') and billing_fy=0
union all
select distinct a.projects , case when(billing_fy!=0)
then(select round(((sum(cost_project)/(sum(billing_fy)/((10/12)*365)))),2) from table1 b    where a.projects = b.projects group by projects)
else 0 end as "WIP days outstanding"
from table1 a
where projects='History - SASAGRAM - MUMBAI' and billing_fy!=0;
```

And this produces the required output

```
Projects                         WIP days outstanding
History - NASIK - MUMBAI         89.92
History - AURANGABAD - MUMBAI    83.25
History - AURANGABAD - NASIK     0
History - PUNE - MUMBAI          0
History - SASAGRAM - MUMBAI      1386.52
```

This is just a shabby way of doing it, and I'd like to know if it is possible to just negate the WHERE clause, or some "neater" alternative to do what I want to do.

Thanks !!

P.S. I use **SQL Developer** and **Oracle 11g** (just in case someone asks)

**EDIT** Input Values as requested

```
Projects                      Cost_Project  Billing_FY
History - NASIK - MUMBAI      65696067.99   54937478.46
History - NASIK - MUMBAI      41385613.61   151909546.44
History - NASIK - MUMBAI      18029488.91   216353866.92
History - AURANGABAD - MUMBAI 33191393.23   57073935.95
History - AURANGABAD - MUMBAI 52681451.68   139055661.74
History - AURANGABAD - MUMBAI 74576522.31   390092578.24
History - PUNE - MUMBAI       0             0
History - PUNE - MUMBAI       0             0
History - PUNE - MUMBAI       0             0
History - SASAGRAM - MUMBAI   107540114.08  40653734.06
History - SASAGRAM - MUMBAI   209167760.1   28823862.66
History - SASAGRAM - MUMBAI   0             0
History - AURANGABAD - NASIK  0             0
History - AURANGABAD - NASIK  0             0
History - AURANGABAD - NASIK  0             0
```

Comment: Please show your example input data. I can't quite make sense of your question but it sounds like you may want to use an outer join instead of "where x = y"

Comment: Isn't outer join used for two individual tables? The query is just referencing one table (same table in the case statement and out of case statement)in any case, I'll edit the input values to the end of my question

Comment: The Oracle SQL syntax clearly supports the NOT operator.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions004.htm#i1052219    So, why not just try it?

Comment: "This is just a shabby way of doing it" -- shabby is in the eye of the beholder. Care to say why you think this?

Comment: Thank you. That was what I was looking for. My first attempt was to use a ! before the statement which didnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, what you want is the `not` operator:

```
select distinct a.projects , case when(billing_fy!=0)
then(select round(((sum(cost_project)/(sum(billing_fy)/((10/12)*365)))),2) 
from table1 b     
where a.projects = b.projects group by projects)
else 0 end as "WIP days outstanding"
from table1 a
where not (projects='History - SASAGRAM - MUMBAI' AND billing_fy=0);
```

As @ShannonSeverance points out, this will cause a problem if you have null values in either field, as `not (false and null)` evaluates to null, which will be treated as false. If you need to make this null safe, so that it only excludes a row that has both of those values, you'd need to do something like this:

```
select distinct a.projects , case when(billing_fy!=0)
then(select round(((sum(cost_project)/(sum(billing_fy)/((10/12)*365)))),2) 
from table1 b
where a.projects = b.projects group by projects)
else 0 end as "WIP days outstanding"
from table1 a
where (not (projects='History - SASAGRAM - MUMBAI' AND billing_fy=0))
      or projects is null 
      or billing_fy is null;
```

Comment: One gotcha to watch for is that SQL supports three value logic. Comparisons to NULL return UNKNOWN. NOT UNKNOWN is UNKNOWN. So you could have a where clause that is excluding some rows because they evaluate to unknown, and saying `where not (prior where criteria)` will still exclude those same rows.

Answer (score 6):

I think this should do it:

```
select distinct a.projects , case when(billing_fy!=0)
then(select round(((sum(cost_project)/(sum(billing_fy)/((10/12)*365)))),2) from table1 b     where a.projects = b.projects group by projects)
else 0 end as "WIP days outstanding"
from table1 a
where (projects != 'History - SASAGRAM - MUMBAI' OR billing_fy != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the following:

```
select distinct a.projects , case when(billing_fy!=0)
then(select round(((sum(cost_project)/(sum(billing_fy)/((10/12)*365)))),2) from table b     where a.projects = b.projects group by projects)
else 0 end as "WIP days outstanding"
from table a
where (projects!='History - SASAGRAM - MUMBAI' AND billing_fy!=0);
```

Comment: I think it should be "OR" (see De Morgan's laws http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: This won't work. He actually is using this query and doing `UNION` with other queries to get the output he needs

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do what you want would be to group, rather than use distinct:

```
select a.projects, 
       case when sum(billing_fy!=0)
            then (select round(((sum(cost_project)/(sum(billing_fy)/((10/12)*365)))),2) 
                  from table1 b
                  where a.projects = b.projects
                  group by projects)
            else 0 end as "WIP days outstanding"
from table1 a
group by a.projects
```